# SqlDataReader can only check for one of (Null or non null value)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqldatareader

I am writing a program (for personal use) that stores card names into a database. I want to implement a way to see if a name already exists and if it does it will go in a "Do_have_in_db_listbox" else it will go in a "do_not_have_list_box". This is my original method for doing so:

```
 while (retrieve.Read())
        {
            if(retrieve["Card"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                listBox_haveInDB.Items.Add(word_for_query);
            }
            else if (retrieve["Card"] == DBNull.Value)
            {
                listBox_notINDb.Items.Add(word_for_query);
            }
        }
```

I've tried this without the While loop, I've tried variations of if, else, else if and conditions. But for whatever reason the else statement NEVER executes no mater what the first condition is. I've been looking and trying to trouble shoot but the only thing that worked for me was an exception handler:
[image: screenshot]

```
retrieve.Read();
try
          {
              if(retrieve["Card"] != DBNull.Value)
              {
                  listBox_haveInDB.Items.Add(word_for_query);
              }
          }
          catch
          {
              listBox_notINDb.Items.Add(word_for_query);
          }
```

This is my way of getting around it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are getting an exception, look at the exception.

Comment: Assuming you have one row per card - is it possible that your select statement just returns an empty result list, which is why you can't just access `retrieve` after `Read()`. 
The `Read()` statement returns a `bool` that indicates if data was read or not (`false` if there was no result to read)

Comment: I suspect the value of retrieve["Card'] is either null or not null, but never DbNull.Value.

Comment: Also.. back to the basics.  Use your DEBUGGER, set a breakpoint to right before it fails and play with it using the immediate window if you can.

Comment: What is your actual query, is it returning `NULL`, how many rows? If it is just one row, one column then you probably want `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate database fields to determine whether their values are DBNull, you can pass the field value to the DBNull.Value.Equals method. However, this method is rarely used.

```
 DBNull.Value.Equals(retrieve["Card"] )
```

Try to use this syntax. That's the most reliable way :

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull( reader.GetOrdinal("Card")))
{
  listBox_haveInDB.Items.Add( ...your code
}
```

or you can use index as well

```
if (!reader.IsDBNull( column_index )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `Card` a field in the datatable? If there is any data in the datatable, the `retrieve["Card"]` will never be null.

> I want to implement a way to see if a name already exists

If you want to check if `word_for_query` exists in datatable, you need to compare `retrieve["Card"].ToString()` with `word_for_query`, rather than `DBNull.Value`.

```
SqlDataReader retrieve = cmd.ExecuteReader();
try
{
    while (retrieve.Read())
    {
        if (retrieve["Card"].ToString() == word_for_query)
        {
            // if exists, show in listBox_haveInDB and return
            listBox_haveInDB.Items.Add(word_for_query);
            return;
        }
    }
    // not exists
    listBox_notINDb.Items.Add(word_for_query);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nError:\n{0}", ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    retrieve.Close();
}
```